# How to click through objects that disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This question is a continuation of [How to click through objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32898855/how-to-click-through-objects)

How do you click through an object, and make the object you're clicking through disappear(or `alpha:0`)

This snippet has four small squares(all with different colors), and one black transparent one which covers all four.

So how can you make it so when you "point" at `#box_a`, you're actually clicking through `#box_e`. Well, you can use `pointer-events: none` on `#box_e` right? But wait a minute I also want `#box_e` to disappear when my mouse is over `#box_e` & to click through it!

By now it's probably evident that I **cant** use **`pointer-events: none`** because then I couldn't read when my mice is over the object in question. How would I do this?

Here is my code(This is a minimalist example):

```js
$(function() {
  $("#box_a").click(function() {
    alert("you clicked box_a")
  });
  $("#box_b").click(function() {
    alert("you clicked box_b")
  });
  $("#box_c").click(function() {
    alert("you clicked box_c")
  });
  $("#box_d").click(function() {
    alert("you clicked box_d")
  });
  $("#box_e").click(function() {
    alert("you clicked box_e(this shouldn't happen!)")
  });
});
```

```css
#box_a, #box_b, #box_c, #box_d {
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 position: relative;
}

#box_a {
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
 background-color: red;
}

#box_b {
 top:-100px;
 left:100px;
 background-color: blue;
}

#box_c {
 top:-100px;
 left:0px;
 background-color: yellow;
}

#box_d {
 top:-200px;
 left:100px;
 background-color: green;
}

#box_e {
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
 top:-400px;
 left:0px;
 background-color: black;
 opacity: .5;
 position: relative;
 pointer-events: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="box_a"></div>
<div id="box_b"></div>
<div id="box_c"></div>
<div id="box_d"></div>
<div id="box_e"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correct, but are you looking for: `#box_a:hover, #box_b:hover, #box_c:hover, #box_d:hover{
    opacity:0;
}`

Comment: I also have trouble parsing your requirements. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: No, "How do you click through an object, and make the object you're clicking through disappear(or `alpha:0`)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `mouseenter`, `mouseleave` and then an `addClass` on the covering div :

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYMjYr)

```
.noevents {
 pointer-events: none;
}
```

```
$('#box_e').mouseenter(function() {    
    $(this).fadeTo(0,0).addClass('noevents');
});

$('.box').mouseleave(function() {
    if (e.relatedTarget.className != 'box') $('#box_e').fadeTo(0,0.5).removeClass('noevents');
})
```

Then remove the class when the mouse is going out of the smaller boxes - and not into another one (which would cause flickering). Only requirement is to give the boxes a common class.

Comment: If you decide to animate the fade, it's a good idea to add a `stop()` to prevent animation queue build up. Something like : `$('#box_e').stop().fadeTo(400,0.5).removeClass('noevents');` @julian avar.

Answer (score 2):

This is the way I understand the inquiry.  You have a box covering the four smaller boxes and you want the big box removed when you hover over it, so that you can click on one of the four boxes "below."

Based on that understanding here's a slightly optimized fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/163vuwgu/.

HTML:

```
<div class = "wrapper">
    <div id="box_a"></div>
    <div id="box_b"></div>
    <div id="box_c"></div>
    <div id="box_d"></div>
</div>
<p id = "status"></p>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    display: table;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#status {
    text-align: center;
}

.wrapper > div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
}

.wrapper > div:nth-of-type(2) {
    background-color: blue;
}

.wrapper > div:nth-of-type(3) {
    background-color: yellow;
    clear: left;
}

.wrapper > div:nth-of-type(4) {
    background-color: green;
}

.wrapper:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.wrapper:hover:before {
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$(".wrapper > div").click(function(e) {
    $("#status").html("You have clicked " + $(this).attr("id") + ".");
});
```

Comment: Awesome! best answer! And thank you, I didn't quite think of that