# How to click through an object that doesn't completely cover the background and disappear on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is an even further continuation to [How to click through objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32898855/how-to-click-through-objects) and to [How to click through objects that disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32925913/how-to-click-through-objects-that-disappear)

This question is much related to [How to click through objects that disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32925913/how-to-click-through-objects-that-disappear), with a small modification.

In the question above, the object that was on top, covered completely the other four boxes. But what if you don't?

Meaning, what if you have four boxes, an `alpha: .5` on top which is the same size that the other four which is centered, and you want to be able to hover over the last box so that it is not visible, and you're able to click in the place where it was before **and** when you move your cursor out of the way, the middle box will go back to it's original state(`alpha: .5`).

And here is where you're implementing it:

```js
$(function() {

  $("#box_a").click(function() {
    alert("you clicked box_a");
  });

  $("#box_b").click(function() {
    alert("you clicked box_b");
  });

  $("#box_c").click(function() {
    alert("you clicked box_c");
  });

  $("#box_d").click(function() {
    alert("you clicked box_d");
  });

  $("#box_e").click(function() {
    alert("you clicked box_e(this shouldn't happen!)");
  }).mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).fadeTo(0,0).addClass("noevents");
  });

  $(".box").mouseleave(function(e) {
    if(e.relatedTarget.className != 'box') {
      $("#box_e").fadeTo(0,0.5).removeClass("noevents");
    }
  })
});
```

```css
#box_a, #box_b, #box_c, #box_d {
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 position: relative;
}

#box_a {
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
 background-color: red;
}

#box_b {
 top:-100px;
 left:100px;
 background-color: blue;
}

#box_c {
 top:-100px;
 left:0px;
 background-color: yellow;
}

#box_d {
 top:-200px;
 left:100px;
 background-color: green;
}

#box_e {
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 top:-350px;
 left:50px;
 background-color: black;
 opacity: .5;
 position: relative;
}

.noevents {
 pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box_a" class="box"></div>
<div id="box_b" class="box"></div>
<div id="box_c" class="box"></div>
<div id="box_d" class="box"></div>
<div id="box_e"></div>
```

As you can see, this code works pretty well, except that when you leave the area where middle box should be, the `#box_e` does not come back, and actually it doesn't go back to `alpha: .5` until your cursor is not over any of the four boxes, which is not what should happen. What should happen is that when you leave the area of where `#box_e` "is" `#box_e` should go back to `alpha: .5` **EVEN** if your cursor is on top of any of the other boxes.

> EDIT

Try to make this so that it doesn't work **just** for this specific example. Your answer **MUST** be flexible to where ever I'm needing to put `#box_e`. Let's say that `#box_e` is one pixel below what it is in this minimalist example, then I would have to modify absolutely everything, which is not the goal here.

Comment: Interested to see any answers here, you're throwing some nice puzzles at us! So far I haven't come up with any slicker than keeping track of the mouse position and calculating where the center element *should* be.

Comment: @Shikkediel Well thank you! I've been trying to this for quite some time now, you see, I'm quite new to the programming world, I would consider myself more of a designer, but as I was getting answers to the other questions, I realized that they didn't quite work for what I was doing, I'm pretty sure that this question will give the answer the what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way, keeping track of where the mouse is (in this case only when it's over the boxes to keep down the impact on performance) and checking if it is outside of where the center element should be :

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LpWrJX?editors=001)

```
$(function() {

var box = $('#box_e'),
w = box.outerWidth(),
h = box.outerHeight(),
xmin = box.offset().left,
xmax = xmin + w,
ymin = box.offset().top,
ymax = ymin + h;

box.mouseenter(function() {

    $(this).fadeTo(0,0).addClass('noevents');
});

$('.box').mousemove(function(e) {

    if (elementOut(e) && box.hasClass('noevents')) {
    box.fadeTo(0,0.5).removeClass('noevents');
    }
});

function elementOut(e) {

var x = e.pageX, y = e.pageY,
onelement = x >= xmin && x <= xmax && y >= ymin && y <= ymax;

return !onelement;
}
});
```

Comment: I simply love it, even when I modify the coordinates of the box it still works(which is exactly what I was looking for)but may I ask, why is it that when you scroll down the box does not work any more. You see when I scroll down, I hover my mouse, everything works fine, but then I move my mouse of where `#box_e` should be, and it doesn't come back to `alpha: .5`

Comment: Good question, let me look into that. I'll see to provide a fix. Edit - already done, I think (using `e.pageX` versus `e.clientX` is always a tricky one).

Comment: Thank you for your hard work! You're surely a talented programmer

Comment: You're very welcome. I consider myself to be a rookie though. Lots to learn still...

Answer (score -1):

I think for this issue you could use pointer-event property as well..

You can change the property when you are hover a box and then change it again when you are out of the box.